# How to call function when load page and when submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to call function when load page and when submit form ?

when i load page i want to call function `function xxx()`

and when i submit form , i want to call `function xxx()` again , how can i do that ?

```
NOTE: this example code call `function xxx()` when submit form only but not call `function xxx()` when load page
```

index.php
.

.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="f1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="number" value="one" onclick="xxx()">1<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="number" value="two" onclick="xxx()">2<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="three" name="number" value="three" onclick="xxx()">3<br>
        </form>
        <div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; text-align: center; padding-top: 25%; cursor: wait; font-size: 24px;">
            LOADING
        </div>


<div id="result">
<script>
function xxx(){
    $('#result').hide();
    $('#overlay').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#overlay').hide();
            $('#result').show();
            $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The nicest jQuery DOM ready syntax is simply `JQuery(function($){ your code here });` this is both a ready event handler and provides a locally scoped `$` value :)

Comment: since my answer solved your problem, could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function xxx() {
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#f1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#result').show();
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    xxx(); // called when page is loaded.
    $("form#f1").submit(function(event) {
        xxx(); // call function when form is submitted.
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function xxx(){
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#f1').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#result').show();
                $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        return false;
    }

    xxx();

    $("form#f1").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        xxx();
    });
});
```

Or, if you don't want to stop your form from submitting, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    xxx();

    $("form#f1").submit(xxx);
});
```

Comment: when i use your code, some function other `function xxx` are mistake process.

Comment: @การรกาารนานนานกาพ what exactly do you mean?

Comment: php loop fetch data from mysql are error loop when use your code .

Comment: @การรกาารนานนานกาพ then the problem should be in your php code (which I can't see), right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: but when i use old code (in my question) , loop php are good , but when i use your code my php loop and other script are mistake process 


can you tell me cause of this issue ?

Comment: @การรกาารนานนานกาพ try doing `$(this).serialize()` instead of `$("#f1").serialize`

Comment: when use `$(this).serialize()` my code are not call ajax

Comment: @การรกาารนานนานกาพ can you post what the data looks like in php when you use `$("#f1").serialize()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
//when the page is loaded

$.ready(function(){

    // call of your function
    xxx();

    $('#f1').submit(function(){
        // new call of your function 
        xxx();
    });

});
```

Comment: +1: Simple and clear. Note: you can also use `JQuery(function($){ code here });` to provide a locally scoped $ as well as DOM ready in one.

Comment: You probably need to `e.preventdefault()` in the submit handler too, as the Ajax call will happen as the page is lost via postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your JavaScript in

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   /* JS HERE */ 
});
```

That only applies when the DOM is ready.

I can't see a submit button in your HTML, but you could bind a click event on that button and then execute a function.

Answer (score 0):

On page load, just run the method on `document.ready`:

```
$(xxx);
```

For a form submission, hook it onto the form submit event:

```
$("#f1").on("submit", xxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the function which is supposed to be runned inside of the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    your code here
});
```

This will call a function, whenever the document is loaded and ready.

In fact that you dont have a submit button in your form, you can do

```
$("#overlay").click(function() {
  your code here
});
```

This will run the code inside the function, whenever the div with the id #overlay is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to do it on load with jquery

```
//Remember to use closure, always!!
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready( function () {
        function xxx () {
            //Do your magic
        }

        xxx();

        $('#your-form').submit(function (e) {
             xxx();
             //if you want to avoid the default submit
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why bother using an IEFE to wrap your code if you do not pass jQuery to it (i.e. to locally scope `$`)? That wrapping will have no useful effect at all.

Comment: A nice shortcut for both locally scoped $ *and* DOM ready is simply `jQuery(function($){code here});` :)

Comment: I no longer use jQuery, I didn't remember how was the correct form, so I use this. Thanks